# How many resources I can get rolling two dice N times

Tags: probability, dice

Two dice rolling N times.

If the sum of the two dice is equal to 6 we get 1 resource.
If the sum of the two dice is equal to 4 we get 2 resources.
Resources are the same.

How many times (N) should I roll two dice in order to get **at least** one (case 1), **at least** two (case 2), **at least** three (case 3) resource(s) with probability 0.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "at least one."

Find the probability of the complement (in $N$ rolls, you get zero resources) as a function of $N$, and set it equal to $0.4$.

> The probability of rolling a sum of 6 or 4 is $p = \frac{8}{36}$. The probability of getting no resources in $N$ rolls is $(1-p)^N$. Set this equal to $0.4$ and solve for $N$.

---

For "at least two."

Again, consider the complement (in $N$ rolls, you get zero resources or exactly one resource). You already computed the probability of zero resources. For one resource, it is $Np_6(1-p_6-p_4)^{N-1}$ where $p_6$ and $p_4$ are the probabilities of rolling a sum of$6$ and $4$  respectively. [There are $N$ ways to choose which roll is the $6$, and the other $N-1$ rolls must be neither $6$ nor $4$.] Sum these two probabilities and set equal to $0.4$.

---

For "at least three" can be solved using further casework on the complement: either zero resources, or one resource, or two resources. In the case of exactly two resources, this can be achieved either by rolling $4$ once, or rolling $6$ twice.

Comment: Am I right?

(7/9)^N=0,4; 
N * ln(7/9) = ln(0,4) -> N = 9 times to get at least one resource? This seems so many.
In case if we get 1 resource from 6 and 4 I think the solution is like:
n = LN(1 - 0.5) / (LN( ( 36 - 3 - 5 ) /36) ) = LN(0.5) / LN( 28 / 36) = 3 times / 1 resource

Comment: @David $\ln(0.4)/\ln(7/9) \approx 3.6$

Comment: just to clarify, how does we take into account that we can get 2 or 1 resource from the two different sums? 3.6 times is like "on average"? So if we roll two dice say 8 times we will get about 2 resources?

Comment: It seems using solution above there is no difference in the amount of resources received from sums.. In case if we get 1 resource from each sum we will get the same solution 3.6 times to get 1 resource

Comment: @David Your question is about getting "at least one" resource, so it doesn't matter if we get 1 or 2 resources after a roll: both are "at least one."

Comment: Could you please tell me how to solve it in case to get at least two/three resources? I wrote this in brackets in the question, it was not clear.

Comment: @David Oh I see, I did not realize you were asking multiple questions (I thought it was a clarification that "at least one" includes "two, three, etc.".)

Comment: @David see my edit

Comment: How do you think is it possible to obtain a general formula for any N?